# Open an exising MVC 3 project in visual studio 11 developer preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I've trying to open and convert an existing vs 2010 mvc 3 project in the new dev 11 preview and am running in to a difficult issue. The solution file will convert successfully,  however the one mvc 3 web project in the solution shows in the solution explorer as unloaded post conversion. When i attempt to reload the project from solution explorer, i get prompted to convert the project and receive the following error in the upgradelog.xml

The project file'myproject.csproj' cannot be opened. There is a missing project subtype. Subtype: '{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}' is unsupported by this installation.

From what i could track down, this has to do with MVC, but that doesn't really help me work around the issue. Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried converting a simple mvc project? You may have run across a bug in the early beta of VS2011

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: Actually, MVC 3 for Visual Studio 11 Dev Preview has just been published: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1491

We have not yet shipped MVC 3 support in Visual Studio 11. You can work around this by editing your csproj file and removing the project type GUID {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}. This will cause your project to load like a normal WAP. You will be able to edit your code, however MVC-specific actions (Add Controller, etc) will not be available.

Comment: is it planned? and if so - how soon?

Comment: @AlexanderTaran It just shipped.

Comment: @Chris yup, just been made available.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the steps from the *Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4* section of the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes), even if the document describes the VS2010 version.

I managed to convert a VS2010/MVC3 project, but VS11 shows a warning every time I open the solution, stating that the project requires *ASP.NET Web pages with Razor syntx 1.0*. OTOH, the project seems to run without any problems (VS11 setup also installed *ASP.NET Web pages 2*).