# Visual Studio 2012 The project type is not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, upgrade

I am having trouble with a web application project that was originally created in VS 2010 and then imported by someone else within our team of 3 developers. The solution is a pretty complex MVC4 project with multiple projects.

When I try and open the solution, I get the project not supported message for the MVC4 web application. All the other projects are class libraries and they load without any problem.

I am the only one of the three who gets this error. Even more strangely, if I share my solution folder the other devs can open my solution without any problem.

I have tried repairing the VS 2012 installation, but still get the error.

I could try doing an uninstall / reinstall, but I am really curious as to why this is happening.

I have looked in the CSPROJ file and found the VisualStudioVersion attribute set to 10.0. Surely this cannot be right?

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If anyone has any explanation for why this problem is occurring, I'd love to hear it!

Thanks

Comment: The solution doesn't happen to have an installer project does it? That project type was dropped in 2012. I realise you've said it's the MVC4 app, i'm just thinking outside the box

Comment: The VS 2010 solution did have an installer project, but given they are no longer supported, it was removed from the solution.

Comment: The version number is fine, VS2012 supports opening VS2010 projects without converting them.  Try removing the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` one by one with a text editor for a better diagnostic.  And of course try creating a new MVC4 app from scratch.

Comment: Removing the only <ProjectTypeGuids> attribute resolved it! I also found this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/b3a23699-580e-433a-b68d-5dbb120f7700 which suggests also removing the <ProjectGUID> tag. Can you pls clarify why this resolves the problem? And put it as a reply so it can be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue of not being able to open a MVC 4 csproj solution in Visual Studio 2012 for the first time.

I had 2 GUID's inside my ProjectTypeGuids element, and my plan was to take one out at a time.  When I removed the [GUID](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx) that corresponded to a Test Project Type, {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}, the project loaded normally.

You may not need to do the nuclear option of removing them all to fix the issue, as it could be related to Test Projects.

Also, it appears that this has happened with previous releases of both Visual Studio and MVC, as there was another Stack Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478513/open-an-exising-mvc-3-project-in-visual-studio-11-developer-preview).

Answer (score 0):

while removing the GUIDs allows the project to load, for my MVC 4 project, I had to uninstall and re-install Visual Studio 2012.

I tried to avoid this by adding all the updates, service packs, and extra components, but none let VS understand that .NET 4.5 / MVC 4 was installed on my machine. In my rush, I lost track of exactly which updates I installed, otherwise I would list them.

The uninstall + re-install allowed VS to understand that .NET 4.5 and MVC 4 were installed on my machine.  Project loads, builds, and runs now.

HTH